# What's the reason for transform: translate when centering an element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to learn to work with percentages in CSS instead of exact units, which led me to this centering technique:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

I know that with absolute positioned elements, the top, bottom, right, and left properties set space between an element and the edge of its ancestor or father if there's one. In the technique they put the element 50% below and 50% to the left which is logical if the intention is to center horizontally and vertically the element, but why include the `transform` property that is used to rotate, scale, and move elements with negative values?

Here's my code:

```css
.container {
  height: 700px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 .container img{
  background-size: cover;
}

.container > h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Enjoy This Magical Experience</h1>
  <img src="https://static.tumblr.com/737181aea20b4523b6fce168a29fe06b/nwsqmvx/cIhmrn4un/tumblr_static_bigstock_silhouettes_of_concert_crowd_i_1565261621.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use `top: 50%; left: 50%` it puts the top/left corner of an element in the center of the screen, which usually means the content of the element will be offset to the right and below the actual center of the screen. `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` moves the element 50% of it's own width up and to the left, centering the content of the element - not just the top/left corner.

Comment: But the element is inside a div so the 50% shouldn't mean that half of its height and half of it width? If that's the case why the -50% is needed?

Comment: *"But the element is inside a div so the 50% shouldn't mean that half of its height and half of it width?"* huh? what "50%"? `top: 50%` puts the **top** edge of the element 50% down on the page, and `left: 50%` puts the **left** edge of the element at 50% of the page width. Which means that if the element has any content in it, the content will be offset to the right and bottom. Using `translateX(-50%)` moves the element back 50% of it's own width to put the horiz center of the element in the center of the x-axis, and `translateY(-50%)` moves the element back up 50% of it's own height to put

Comment: the vertical center of the element at the center/50% of the y-axis

Comment: Ohh, I see. I thought that the 50% meant 50% percent of its container. Now, I got two other questions:

Comment: 1) How do I know that the `translateX(-50%) ` will center on the x-axis. Of course it works, but I really want lo learn why that works.                                 2)How do I set the space of an element using % that depends of the containers properties, such as setting and elements height by half of its container size?

Comment: Play with it and see. Add `position: absolute; left: 50%` to something and see where it goes. Then add `transform: translateX(-50%);` and see what happens. You'll figure it out. If you want an element's height to be 50% of it's container height, add `height: 50%`. All of this stuff can be found by looking up `height` or `transform: translateX()` or `left` or `right` or whatever and reading the css specs.

Comment: Mr Michael, I've finished the codeacademy css and html course I'm not asking because I don't know and I'm too lazy to read, I'm doing it because although I finished I've got some doubts. The reason I thought `top:50%` meant half of its container height it's because I thought it behavior was just like height and width.

Comment: if the parent is `position: relative/fixed/absolute` (non-`static`), then `position: absolute; top: 50%;` on a child element in that parent does mean "50% down from the top of the parent container".

Comment: That was my mistake, my container was static so the top had no effect on it. Thank you Michael!!

Answer (score 0):

### `top`/`left`

`top` moves top border of your element *x* units from top border of container (or element we are placing out element relative to).

`left` moves left border of your element *x* units from left border of container (or element we are placing out element relative to).

**Percentage in both of them is calculated from container**.

Basically `top: 50%; left: 50%` puts your element's top-left corner in the center of container.

### `translate`

`translate`(X/Y) moves your element by *x* units from it's current position.

In this case **percentage is calculated from the element itself**.

`translate(-50%, -50%)` moves your element by half of its width and half of its height back (root `0,0` point is in top-left corner and numbers are increasing into visible area).

Comment: I understand the properties, but what I don't is why the -50% is needed. The element is inside a div so the 50% shouldn't mean that half of its height and half of it width? If that's the case why the -50% is needed?

Comment: @ElioBriceño Read again first part because you do not understand properties. `top` moves **top border** of your element *x* units from top border of container. If you move it by `50%` then it means **top border** is moved by half of container's height. Due to that you center element's top-left corner **not** the element.